Logstash pipelines.yml File Command Not Found
Im trying to run Logstash on Amazon ECS via Docker.
The service runs up well but fails right after because its not recognizing the pipelines.yml file commands. Here the application logs:
/usr/share/logstash/config/pipelines.yml: path.config:: command not found


/usr/share/logstash/config/pipelines.yml: -: command not found

The pipelines.yml file just have a several configuration about the pipelines:
...

- pipeline.id: 
  path.config:

- pipeline.id: 
  path.config:

...

But seems its not recognizing the commands to start the pipelines.
I did not tried anything yet because I did not found anyone else having this issue.
Maybe some missing configuration on Dockerfile ?

Does the docker container work if you run it locally? That configuration file looks completely wrong to me. path.config is a configuration attribute you should be providing a value for, not providing it as a value for other configurations.
